# How to remove certain number elements from an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var numbers = [1,2,0,3,0,4,0,5];
```

If I have the above array and I want to remove the 0s and output an array of [1,2,3,4,5] how would I do it?

I have the below code but I am getting an "TypeError: arr.includes is not a function" error...

```
var zero = 0;

var x = balDiffs.map(function(arr, i) {
  console.log(arr);
  if(arr.includes(zero)) {
    return i;
  }
});
```

Comment: `Array.filter`?

Comment: do you always want to filter zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) function as the callback. The Boolean function will return `false` for 0, and `true` for other numbers:

```js
var numbers = [1,2,0,3,0,4,0,5];

var result = numbers.filter(Boolean);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: He did say - "I want to remove the 0s".

Comment: As clever as this answer is, it doesn't answer the question based on the heading _"remove certain number elements"_. My read on the question is that zero is just an example in this case. Something like `numbers.filter(n => n !== 0)`, would both be more clear and adaptable to values other than zero.

Comment: Both ways work, but I did mean just the 0s.  Sorry for the ambiguity.  Thank you all of you.

Answer (score 3):

[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns an array with the same length as the given array, but it can change the values of each element.

Then you took an element for [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) or [`String#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) but that does not work with numbers.

But even if that works, you would get only zeroes and `undefined` with the given approach.

---

You could use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and filter the unwanted value.

```js
var numbers = [1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5],
    value = 0,                                   // or any other value
    filtered = numbers.filter(v => v !== value);
    
console.log(filtered);
```

Approach with more than one unwanted value.

```js
var numbers = [1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5],
    unwanted = [0, 3],
    filtered = numbers.filter(v => !unwanted.includes(v));
    
console.log(filtered);
```